# Problems installing Jasperserver with Powershell. ANT can't see Java

Tags: java, powershell, batch-file, ant, jasperserver

I'm trying to install Jasperserver onto a Windows VM with Powershell.

I can install Java just fine, but some subsequent bat files that get run are complaining they can't find environment variables such as JAVA_HOME.  I can see they exist however.

I add the environment variables:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91", "Machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JRE_HOME", "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91", "Machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("CLASSPATH", "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre1.8.0_91\lib\rt.jar", "Machine")
```

And also the path variable.  Going into System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment variables I can see they are there, so I assume it's not just setting the powershell session.

When I try to run ANT (though a build in batch)

cd C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-6.2.0\apache-tomcat\bin
$arguments = '/c service.bat install'
Start-Process cmd -Wait -PassThru -ArgumentList $arguments

it gives me this error:

```
> WARNING: JAVA_HOME environment variable not found  [minimal]  Running
> install-minimal-pro Ant task 
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------  '"java.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file. Checking Ant return code: OK
```

I've tried:

- Setting the environments several ways (setx.exe, etc)
- Running the bat in many ways, start-process, cmd, in an invoke-command, etc

If I reboot the server it will install fine.  Also, if I run the batch directly in a command prompt it's fine.

Before I have to use an image with Java already installed, I want to understand why this is happening and ideally make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `SetEnvironmentVariable(..., "Machine")` and `setx` set the variable in the registry.  This value is used for future processes launched by explorer (such as after a reboot), but it is NOT set for the current process or its children.  Your script needs to set the variables for the *current process*.

Using the .NET syntax:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91", "Process")
```

Or, using PS syntax

```
$env:JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91"
```